# How do I get a path to an image?

Tags: java, image, path

I tried to do this:

```
Path pathForSpriteSheet = Paths.get("/PicFolder/TheSpriteSheet.png");
```

Then I put it in this method like this:

```
loadImage(pathForSpriteSheet);
public void loadImage(BufferedImage image){
    theImage = image;
}
```

It says *"The method loadImage(BufferedImage) in the type BufferedImageLoader is not applicable for the arguments"*

Comment: As the message tells you, the method `loadImage` wants a `BufferedImage`, but you pass a `Path` variable. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

To further what Tom said, you cannot pass a `Path` variable to the method `loadImage` when it requires a `BufferedImage`. What you need to do is create a `BufferedImage` based off of the path you already have and send *that* to the method. Something like:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(pathForSpriteSheet.toFile());
loadImage(img);
```

Comment: I tried that: private BufferedImage theImage = ImageIO.read(pathForSpriteSheet.toFile());

Comment: You can't possibly be doing it correctly if you have `private` in front of it. What I wrote has to be called inside of a method.